# javascript import statement without node

Tags: javascript

I want to include a javscript file found on 
https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js

it states it works on node and in the browser via CDN.

So I included the script tag in the header:

```
<script scrc="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/regression/1.4.0/regression.min.js"></script>
```

README tells me:

```
import regression from 'regression';
result = regression.linear([[0, 1], [32, 67], [12, 79]]);
```

since I dont use node.js I just removed the import statement. However browser is telling me: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'linear' of undefined`

any ideas?

Comment: as I said, I removed the "import statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDN script tag you used in the header refers **to version 1.4.0**
You can use it like ...

```
result = regression('linear',[[0, 1], [32, 67], [12, 79]]);
console.log(result.equation);
console.log(result.points);
```

Version 1.4.0 unfortunately doesn't have the predict function. It was added in **version 2.0.0.**

However, if you include that version, you need to change the way you call functions to ...

```
result = regression.linear([[0, 1], [32, 67], [12, 79]]);
console.log(result.equation);
console.log(result.points);
```

now you can use ...

```
console.log(result.predict(4));
```

Comment: awesome, the last thing I wonder is how the `predict` function works: `console.log(result.predict(4));` ?!?!

Comment: Version 1.4.0 unfortunately doesn't have the predict function. It was added in 2.0.0 but cloudflare CDN doesn't have it. You could use result.equation to calculate the predicted answer for a certain x OR include version 2.0.0 of this library in your webpage: https://github.com/Tom-Alexander/regression-js/blob/master/dist/regression.min.js

Comment: Version 2.0.0 also added a new way to call functions. They are now separate methods. I've updated my answer